# Parallel Task Wait from UI without blocking

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I using the Parallel Task library to run async tasks in the background. Sometimes I have to wait that background task's completed delegate while the UI thread is non-blocked.

So:

1. in UI thread start a spinner
2. in background do some work that needs to be wait
3. after that run another background task
4. stop the spinner in the UI

I started the background task in the UI thread (2) after that I tried to call Wait method, which is cause a deadlock...

I need a solution to wait a specified background task without blocking the UI thread. .NET framework is 4 so I can't use `async` and `await`

Update:

In the UI thread:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew<T>(() => BackgroundTask());
task.ContinueWith(task => CompletedTask(((Task<T>)task).Result); // I want to prevent later tasks to start before this task is finished
task.Wait(); // this will block the ui...
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Are you on Visual Studio 2012 or newer? If so you can use the package [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) to enable async/await in .NET 4.0

Comment: Unfortunately just VS 2010

Comment: Use Stephen Toub's `Then` or `Iterate` patterns. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22291625/1768303

Answer (score 1):

You use `ContinueWith` to attach a continuation to the task and run some code when the task finishes.  `await` is doing effectively the same thing, behind the scenes.

You can use `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` to run a continuation when all of a collection of tasks have finished.

You can use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` from within the UI thread to get a task scheduler capable of scheduling tasks in the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried it (maybe I made a mistake or didn't get the point) but it didn't worked. 
When I call the background task in the UI thread I set ContinueWith in the completed task. But later in the UI thread I start another task. And I want to wait to the first task is completed. That's why I try to use Wait.

Comment: @hcpeter please show what you tried as a edit to your question, we can help you correct your mistake then.

Comment: @hcpeter Store a reference to the task, and at some later point in time when you want to do something after that task has finished, add a continuation to it, instead of waiting on it.