# How to asynchronously make a web request without a callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-4.0, async-await

I have a service that talks to a 3rd party on the internet, if i want this to scale i don't want my threads to be blocked waiting for the response when they could be handling new requests. One way around this is to use the httpRequest.BeginGetResponse method and pass in a callback. The issue with this is this method returns immediately and i have nothing to give back to the caller of my service. Once in the callback i cant do anything useful.

What i would like is something like this

```
public string CallServiceNonBlocking(string url) {

   var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

   HttpResponse res = httpRequest.FetchNonBlocking(); //this does the work but my thread should  be returned to the asp.net thread pool to do other work rather than blocking here

   return res.GetValue(); 

}
```

Note i don't have .Net 4.5 available to me only .NET 4. But for reference can i see a solution for both versions?

Comment: Your CallServiceNonBlocking would have to take a completion handler/callback for when your fetch is complete. You *can* use the TPL in .NET 4.0.

Comment: can you show me how this looks please?

Comment: You might want to check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Async bubbles up to every caller. There is no free lunch.

Comment: `i don't want my threads to be blocked waiting for the response when they could be handling new requests` Maybe just increase the worker thread count? That's a very simple solution up to a point.

Answer (score 2):

Coding this with .NET 4.5 and C# 5.0 `async/await` is [very easy](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

You can make it work asynchronously with .NET 4.0 / C# 4.0 too, if you have to. You'd need to derive your controller from [`AsyncController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and use [`AsyncManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.async.asyncmanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The basic steps are described in ["Using an Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In this light, your code may look like this (untested):

```
static public Task<WebResponse> GetResponseTapAsync(this WebRequest request)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
         (asyncCallback, state) =>
             request.BeginGetResponse(asyncCallback, state),
         (asyncResult) =>
             request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult), null);
}

// ...

public class YourController : AsyncController
{
    public void YourMethodAsyc(string url)
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.GetResponseTapAsync().ContinueWith(responseTask =>
        {
            try
            {
                var stream = responseTask.Result.GetResponseStream();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    // still blocking here, see notes below
                    var data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                    AsyncManager.Parameters["data"] = data;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    public ActionResult YourMethodCompleted(string data)
    {
        return View("Data", new ViewModel
        {
            Data = data
        });
    }
}
```

You could take it further and implement `ReadToEndAsync` (as it is absent in .NET 4.0), but you won't be able to use `using`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22291625/1768303) for some more details.

Ideally, if you need to target ASP.NET MVC with .NET 4.0, but develop with VS2012+ in C# 5.0, you still can use `async/await`, Microsoft provides [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) library for that. Then your code might look like this:

```
public class YourController : AsyncController
{
    async Task<string> YourMethodAsyncImpl(string url)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync()
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            return await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    public void YourMethodAsyc(string url)
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

        YourMethodAsyncImpl(url).ContinueWith(resultTask =>
        {
            try
            {
                AsyncManager.Parameters["data"] = resultTask.Result;
            }
            finally
            {
                AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    public ActionResult YourMethodCompleted(string data)
    {
        return View("Data", new ViewModel
        {
            Data = data
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. (NuGet "Rx-Main")

It's then super easy.

Define your function like this:

```
public IObservable<string> CallServiceNonBlocking(string url)
{
    return Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpResponse res = httpRequest.FetchBlocking();
        return res.GetValue(); 
    });
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
CallServiceNonBlocking(url)
    .Subscribe(response =>
    {
        /* handle response here */
    });
```

It's easy to use an `ObserveOn` to make the subscription run on the UI thread, or current context, etc.

Comment: I don't think this would help the OP's web service to scale better, as it's still blocking at least one pool thread for `FetchBlocking`.